# How to connect to postgresql on host from docker container in Ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

In general docker is used, it has two containers: nginx and a container for django.
Postgresql is on the host separately, not in the docker container.

I tried to do something like this in postgresql config:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

So, we allow anyone to connect to anyone, because as I understand the address of the container is changing, but I think this is not very safe.

Tried in docker-compose specify containers network_mode: "host" and change a little config nginx, yes in this case works, but I do not like the idea that all addresses will be "merged" with the host.

Also tried this:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

And also doesn't work.

In all cases I got error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "172.17.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Is there any other way to connect to postgresql from the container?
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Back: Django

[Config docker-compose](https://gist.github.com/RDanned/d4f5fa6174ba820f6312c2b04bc7d55e)

[Dockerfile config](https://gist.github.com/RDanned/c5bc2601c7ae575dccf96d17156e5f0d)

Comment: Hey Ruslan, make sure your host listens on 172.17.0.1 ip address. Use netstat to figure out which ip address postgresql is expecting connections on.

Comment: It allows everyone who knows the password to connect to PostgreSQL, provided they can get to the host in the first place.  It doesn't control what else they can connect to.  If you pick passwords that don't suck and your users don't change them to ones that do, this should be very safe.  Presumably people from the outside world shouldn't be allowed to connect, but that would generally be handled already with a firewall.

Comment: Maybe easier to create a Docker Container running Postgres in the same docker network. Then point the database to where the database is on the host (Volumes in docker-compose). Then you don't have the trouble of trying to access the Host out of a Docker Container.